# How to check data in each shard of mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I create two shard, and key is age like below:

```
db.runCommand({addshard: "localhost:10000", allowLocal: true, maxsize: 0.1, minkey: 1, maxkey: 1})
db.runCommand({addshard: "localhost:10001", allowLocal: true, maxsize: 0.1, minkey: 2, maxkey: 2})

db.runCommand({enablesharding: "foo"})
db.runCommand({shardcollection: "foo.items", key: {"age": 1, "_id":1}, unique: true})
```

How do I check data in whcih shard ?
Or how could i get data from specified shard ?
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to know which shard holds how much data, you can use the

```
db.printShardingStatus();
```

command.

I didn't try it myself, but I think it should be possible to query a specific shard when you use the mongo program to connect to the mongod process of the shard directly instead of the mongos router process. In any case, you should only do this for troubleshooting. Your application should trust mongos to distribute queries to the correct shard and not access the shards directly.